# How does gwt create the first view of my application with ActivityManager, PlaceHistoryHandler?

Tags: java, gwt

When developing with GWT, in my Main entrypoint class, onModuleLoad() method,I have some lines like these:

```
...
activityManager.setDisplay(main);  //main is just a SimplePanel;
...
placeHistoryHandler.register(factory.getPlaceController(), eventBus, new OverviewPlace(""));
...
placeHistoryHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
...
```

How do these lines lead me to my first view? Like a LoginPanel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will not lead to LoginPanel. It will lead to a view associated with OverviewPlace.

If you want a user to go to LoginPanel, you need to replace OverviewPlace with a Place that is linked to LoginPanel view.

Comment: This is exactly what I am curious about. Our first view is a LoginPanel. If you log in, you'll see this OverviewPanel then. Maybe we did sth. elsewhere to have this result.

Comment: It's possible that you redirect a user who is not authenticated to LoginPanel even before this code is called.